# Find Average Sales Amount Per Customer using AdventureWorks2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, adventureworks

I am following a tutorial using MS AdventureWorks2012 and I wanted to write a query to find average sales amount per customer (or in other words, Average Sales for each customer) using AdventureWorks2012. Below is my attempt and it doesn't run. What Am I doing wrong here ?

```
SELECT  soh.CustomerID AS 'Customer ID'
,p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName AS 'Customer Name'
,AVG(soh.TotalDue) AS 'Average Sales Amount Per Customer'
FROM  Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh
INNER JOIN Sales.Customer AS c ON c.CustomerID = soh.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityContact AS bec ON bec.PersonID = c.PersonID
INNER JOIN Person.Person AS p ON p.BusinessEntityID = bec.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY p.FirstName , p.LastName, soh.CustomerID;
```

Comment: "doesn't run" . . . What does it do?  If it returns an error, edit your question and include the error.

Comment: No errors and no rows either. Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query *runs*, it just returns an empty result set.

If you look at `BusinessEntityContact`, it relates a `BusinessEntityID`, which is a customer business, to a `PersonID`, who is a person that is the contact for the business. So if you change your query to this:

```
SELECT  soh.CustomerID AS 'Customer ID', p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName AS 'Customer Name',
    AVG(soh.TotalDue) AS 'Average Sales Amount Per Customer'
FROM  Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh
INNER JOIN Sales.Customer AS c ON c.CustomerID = soh.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityContact AS bec ON bec.PersonID = c.PersonID
INNER JOIN Person.Person AS p ON p.BusinessEntityID = bec.PersonID
GROUP BY p.FirstName , p.LastName, soh.CustomerID;
```

(note the third inner join)
You will get 635 rows.

Comment: Thanks for the help, by the way, It works now. In BusinessEntityContact table, BusinessEntityID and PersonID column content are not the same, How did you identify that, p.BusinessEntityID = bec.PersonID ? is there a why to identify what column of table A matches with which column in table B ?.  When column names are the same, its easy to identify, When they are not the same just like in this case, How do you figure that for sure ?

Comment: Oki, I figured that out, When you click on the Keys folder of BusinessEntityContact, and select "Script the keys" by right clicking on all the keys, you can figure that out by looking at the generated script.

Comment: I find it easier to use `sp_fkeys`, as in this example: 

`EXEC sp_fkeys @fktable_name = N'BusinessEntityContact', @fktable_owner = N'Person';`

Comment: TX, That is mush better and easy , Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

In SQL single quote ' identifies a string. If you *must* to have spaces in your result column names then you can identify column names with double quotes " or preferably by wrapping the column name in square brackes.

```
SELECT  
     soh.CustomerID AS [Customer ID]
    ,p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName AS [Customer Name]
    ,AVG(soh.TotalDue) AS [Average Sales Amount Per Customer]
FROM  Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh
   INNER JOIN Sales.Customer AS c ON c.CustomerID = soh.CustomerID
   INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityContact AS bec ON bec.PersonID = c.PersonID
   INNER JOIN Person.Person AS p ON p.BusinessEntityID = bec.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY p.FirstName , p.LastName, soh.CustomerID;
```

Otherwise your syntax looks okay to me

Comment: Hi Robert, tx for the reply. I didn't get a syntax error, but this query doesn't return any rows. May be my logic is incorrect.

Comment: If that's the case then check your inner joins as you're likely got a problem in one of your ON clauses. The easiest way to check that is to comment out each join until you start to get some results.